# Extract number within brackets at the end of a string - (YYYY)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, dataset, data-cleaning

I am trying to create two separate columns in R. The issue I am running into is that the year does not separate from the previous column depending on the type of observation.

Some names in the data frame are just first names and others have first and last. I am trying to have the `Name` display first and first/last and `Year` be separate from the current `Name` column.

Fake data = Employee and the year they started employment

Create data frame

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(Name = c("Percy Vere (2020)", "Ginger Plant (2017)", "Perry (2019)",
                    "Pat Thettick (2020)", "Samuel (2022)", "Fay Daway (2008)",
                    "Greg (2022)", "Simon Sais (2011)"))
```

```
# A tibble: 8 x 1
  Name               
  <fct>              
1 Percy Vere (2020)  
2 Ginger Plant (2017)
3 Perry (2019)       
4 Pat Thettick (2020)
5 Samuel (2022)      
6 Fay Daway (2008)   
7 Greg (2022)        
8 Simon Sais (2011)
```

Attempt separating the column into two: `Name` and `Year`

```
dat %>% 
  select_all() %>% 
  separate(col = Name, into = c('Name', 'Year')) %>%    # sep = ',' and ';' does not create a fix 
  tibble()

# A tibble: 8 x 2
  Name   Year    
  <chr>  <chr>   
1 Percy  Vere    
2 Ginger Plant   
3 Perry  2019    
4 Pat    Thettick
5 Samuel 2022    
6 Fay    Daway   
7 Greg   2022    
8 Simon  Sais    
Warning message:
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 8 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].
```

Comment: You can `separate(col = Name, into = c('Name', 'Year'), sep = ' \\(' )` and then remove the ")" from the Year column.

Comment: @Dave2e separate has been deprecated. The standard now is to use `separate_wider_*()` and `separate_longer_*()`. See my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `extract`:

```
dat %>% 
   extract(Name, c("Name", "Year"), "(.*) .*?(\\d+)")
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Name         Year 
  <chr>        <chr>
1 Percy Vere   2020 
2 Ginger Plant 2017 
3 Perry        2019 
4 Pat Thettick 2020 
5 Samuel       2022 
6 Fay Daway    2008 
7 Greg         2022 
8 Simon Sais   2011
```

---

Use`separate`:

```
dat %>%
   separate(Name, c("Name", "Year"), " \\(|\\)", extra = 'drop')

# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Name         Year 
  <chr>        <chr>
1 Percy Vere   2020 
2 Ginger Plant 2017 
3 Perry        2019 
4 Pat Thettick 2020 
5 Samuel       2022 
6 Fay Daway    2008 
7 Greg         2022 
8 Simon Sais   2011
```

---

use `str_extract`:

```
dat %>% 
   mutate(Year = str_extract(Name, '\\d+'), Name = str_extract(Name, "\\D+(?= )"))
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Name         Year 
  <chr>        <chr>
1 Percy Vere   2020 
2 Ginger Plant 2017 
3 Perry        2019 
4 Pat Thettick 2020 
5 Samuel       2022 
6 Fay Daway    2008 
7 Greg         2022 
8 Simon Sais   2011
```

---

Using `str_remove`

```
dat %>% 
    mutate(Year = str_remove_all(Name, '\\D+'), Name = str_remove(Name, " [(]\\d+[)]"))
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Name         Year 
  <chr>        <chr>
1 Percy Vere   2020 
2 Ginger Plant 2017 
3 Perry        2019 
4 Pat Thettick 2020 
5 Samuel       2022 
6 Fay Daway    2008 
7 Greg         2022 
8 Simon Sais   2011
```

Comment: *["`separate()` has been superseded in favour of `separate_wider_position()` and `separate_wider_delim()` because the two functions make the two uses more obvious, the API is more polished, and the handling of problems is better. Superseded functions will not go away, but will only receive critical bug fixes."](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html)* - heads up to anyone using `separate()`

Comment: [the same applies to `extract()` too](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html)

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're looking for is `separate_wider_regex()`

```
dat |> 
  separate_wider_regex(Name, patterns = c(Name = ".*(?= \\()", " \\(", Year = "\\d{4}", "\\)")) |> 
  mutate(Year = as.integer(Year))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  Name          Year
  <chr>        <int>
1 Percy Vere    2020
2 Ginger Plant  2017
3 Perry         2019
4 Pat Thettick  2020
5 Samuel        2022
6 Fay Daway     2008
7 Greg          2022
8 Simon Sais    2011
```

Or if you're wanting names to be split up further:

```
dat |> 
  separate_wider_regex(Name, patterns = c(`First Name` = ".*?(?= )", "\\s*", `Last Name` = ".*(?= \\()", " \\(", Year = "\\d{4}", "\\)")) |> 
  mutate(Year = as.integer(Year), 
        `Last Name` = ifelse(nchar(`Last Name`), `Last Name`, NA_character_))
```

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  `First Name` `Last Name`  Year
  <chr>        <chr>       <int>
1 Percy        Vere         2020
2 Ginger       Plant        2017
3 Perry        NA           2019
4 Pat          Thettick     2020
5 Samuel       NA           2022
6 Fay          Daway        2008
7 Greg         NA           2022
8 Simon        Sais         2011
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `read.table` + `sub`

```
> read.table(text = sub("\\((.*)\\)", ",\\1", dat$Name), sep = ",")
             V1   V2
1   Percy Vere  2020
2 Ginger Plant  2017
3        Perry  2019
4 Pat Thettick  2020
5       Samuel  2022
6    Fay Daway  2008
7         Greg  2022
8   Simon Sais  2011
```